# Whats time complexity of this python function?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

```
def hasPairWithSum(arr,target):
     for i in range(len(arr)):
         if ((target-arr[i])  in arr[i+1:]):
             return True

    return False
```

In python, is time complexity for this function O(n) or O(n^2), in other words 'if ((target-arr[i])  in arr[i+1:])' is this another for loop or no?
Also what about following function, is it also O(n^2), if not why:

```
def hasPairWithSum2(arr,target):
   seen = set() 
   for num in arr:
      num2 = target - num
      if num2 in seen:
         return True
      seen.add(num)
   return False
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if ((target-arr[i])  in arr[i+1:])` is another loop. It needs to compare each element of the list `arr[i+1:]`. A way to avoid this is to create a set, dictionary, or some other data structure that allows constant time inclusion tests.

Comment: Yes, O(n^2) because the x in y is executed as a loop by python.

Comment: If you created a `s = set(arr)` and used `in s` instead of `in arr[i+1:]` it would be O(n)

Comment: @MarkMeyer, quamrana  Thanks for the reply, I edited the question, can you please reply to that. Thanks!

Comment: @Moosefeather, how, can you please explain? thanks

Comment: @Neo sorry I was wrong set lookup is [O(n) worst case](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version has a *O(n²)* time complexity:

Indeed the `arr[i+1:]` already creates a new list with *n-1-i* elements, which is not a constant time operation. The `in` operator will *scan* that new list, and in worst case visit each value in that new list.

If we count the number of elements copied into a new list (with `arr[i+1`), we can sum those counts for each iteration of the outer loop:

```
  n-1
+ n-2
+ n-3
+ ...
+ 1
+ 0
```

This is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), and equals *n(n-1)/2*, which is *O(n²)*.

### Second version

The second version, using a `set`, runs in *O(n)* average time complexity.

There is no list slicing here, and the `in` operator on a set has -- contrary to a list argument -- an *average constant* time complexity. So now every action within the loop has an (average) constant time complexity, giving the algorithm an average time complexity of *O(n)*.

According to the [python docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), the `in` operator for a set can have an amortised *worst* time complexity of *O(n)*. So you would still get a *worst* time complexity for your algorithm of *O(n²)*.

Comment: Thank you very much trincot!

Answer (score 0):

It's O(n^2)

First  loop will run n times and second will run (n-m) for every n.
So the whole thing will run **n(n-m)** times that is **n^2 - nm**. Knowing that  **m<n** we know that it has a complexity of O(n^2)

But if it's critical to something you might consult someone who is better at that.

Comment: *m<n* is not an enough condition to conclude that *n²-nm* is *O(n²)*. For instance, if *m=n-1*, then we have *n²-nm* = *n²-n(n-1)* = *n*. Similarly, if *m=n-2*, then it will equal *2n*... etc.